# Which one takes precedence? String Pool Vs String provided by Dependency Injection

Tags: android, string, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I had this question from long time and have been talking to people around me about this.

Say we have a string which is provided by AppModule using Dagger Hilt. This string has no Singleton annotation. It is injected wherever required. Now question is, Is this string created always when it is used in the code or it just picks from string pool with single instance of it in memory?

I have got answers on both side saying string pool works as usual even with DI's and also few said Dependency Injection has to do its job by providing multiple instance of string(as its not singleton). I was curious about this and waned to know what community thinks or even the actual stuff under the hood.

For more clarity I'll post sample code as well,

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideUrl() = "https://openapiaj.org/"

}
```

I hope the question is clear. Curious to see answers from community.

Comment: IMO Since you are defining the way to provide Object dagger has nothing to do with it . This is a String literal So it will use a Single object from String pool if available . On other hand `fun provideUrl() = new String("https://openapiaj.org/")` this will create a new object every time . You can easily test this with `==` operator .

Comment: Makes sense @ADM